# Why can "dash -c ':'" fail with dash 0.5.8 built from source?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, posix, dash-shell

With a dash binary compiled from source (version 0.5.8, available at http://gondor.apana.org.au/~herbert/dash/files/dash-0.5.8.tar.gz), executing

```
dash -c ':'
```

fails with

```
dash: 1: :: Permission denied
```

This means that constructs such as

```
case foo in
*bar*) :
   do_stuff ;;
*) :
   ;;
esac
```

fails, which breaks a lot of scripts. Why do the dash binary distributed with ubuntu not have this problem?

Comment: CNR. Ran my own build, no failure from that same command.

Comment: `$ ~/local/opt/dash-0.5.8/bin/dash -c ': && echo "null command exited successfully"'`; only output: `null command exited successfully`

Comment: I'm curious, by the way -- do you get the same failure from `true`? If you read the source, `true` and `:` are implemented identically.

Comment: Hm, true works, : does not.

Comment: Which os did you try it on? Just tested that both true and : work on OS X for me, but : does not work when compiling from source on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Any chance there could be any hidden characters in the code you're running locally, such that it's not byte-for-byte identical to what you posted here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78048/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-fornwall).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `LC_ALL` is set to collation order which differs from the ASCII byte-order default (`LC_ALL=C`), `mkbuiltins` can generate an array in `builtins.c` in which `bsearch()` can fail to find builtins.

This is definitely a bug, and should be reported upstream.

Comment: Reported in http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.dash/1119 - thanks for all the help!